# Converting Colors

Tags: java, colors

I'm trying to write a method for my game that will take an image, the hex value for the old color, and the hex value for the new color and then convert all pixels of the old color to the new color. Right now, the method paints the entire image the new color, as if the if statement is not working at all. This the method:

```
private void convertColors(BufferedImage img, int oldColor, int newColor)
{
    Graphics g = img.getGraphics();
    g.setColor(new Color(newColor));
    Color old = new Color(oldColor);

    for(int x = 0; x < img.getWidth(); x++)
    {
        for(int y = 0; y < img.getHeight(); y++)
        {
            Color tmp = new Color(img.getRGB(x, y));
            if(tmp.equals(old));
            {
                System.out.println("Temp=" + tmp.toString() + "Old=" + old.toString() + "New=" + g.getColor().toString());
                g.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
            }
        }
    }
    g.dispose();
}
```

*The hex for oldColor is `0xFFFFFF` (white) and for newColor is `0xFF0000` (red).

Using the println method I get these kind of results:

```
    Temp=java.awt.Color[r=0,g=0,b=0]Old=java.awt.Color[r=255,g=255,b=255]New=java.awt.Color[r=255,g=0,b=0]
Temp=java.awt.Color[r=255,g=255,b=255]Old=java.awt.Color[r=255,g=255,b=255]New=java.awt.Color[r=255,g=0,b=0]
```

The scond line looks correct, the temp color and the old are the same, but that is obviously not the case with the first. I have also tried creating a new BufferedImage and copy over the pixels but that leaves the same result... Does the equals method not work as I think it does or does this entire method just not work and there's a better way to do this? Thanks for you help in advance.

Comment: Getting the colors with getRGB, and drawing tiny rectangles - this will be slow, especially for a game. The fast way would be to manipulate directly the int array that is behind a BufferedImage, and then draw the altered image in one go.

Comment: @lbalazscs you are right about that, i´m currently googling how to implement and rgb-filter that fits his need. but since he changes the graphics of the image would it not be enough to call this function once and after that the stored image has correct colors!?

Comment: @lbalazscs When I try to do that: if(pixels[x + y * img.getWidth()] == oldColor)
    {
     pixels[x + y * img.getWidth()] = newColor;
    } it goes into the if statement but the change never shows up though I call setRGB: newImg.setRGB(0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), pixels, 0, img.getWidth()); btw, what is the offset and scansize for?

Comment: @lbalazscs Nvm, I solved it :3

Comment: @luk2302 I didn't look into the details, of course if it makes sense to cache the result of the image transformation, then it should be cached.

Comment: I would actually recommend using `image.setRGB(int x, int y, int color)`.

Comment: @AlexL. Yes, that probably would be faster.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got it to work; this is the working convertColors method:

```
    private BufferedImage convertColors(BufferedImage img, int oldColor, int newColor)
{
    int [] pixels = new int [img.getWidth() * img.getHeight()];
    img.getRGB(0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), pixels, 0, img.getWidth());
    Color old = new Color(oldColor);
    Color newC = new Color(newColor);

    for(int x = 0; x < img.getWidth(); x++)
    {
        for(int y = 0; y < img.getHeight(); y++)
        {
            Color tmp = new Color(pixels[x + y * img.getWidth()]);
            if(tmp.equals(old))
            {
                pixels[x + y * img.getWidth()] = newC.getRGB();
            }
        }
    }
    img.setRGB(0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), pixels, 0, img.getWidth());

    return newImg;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just remove the `;` after `if(tmp.equals(old))`.
Otherwise you compare the colors and do nothing after the comparsion and always choose the new color.

Besides that you need to reorganize your code a little bit to make it slightly more efficient:

```
Graphics g = img.getGraphics();
g.setColor(new Color(newColor));

for(int x = 0; x < img.getWidth(); x++) {
    for(int y = 0; y < img.getHeight(); y++) {
        if(img.getRGB(x, y) == oldColor) {//check if pixel color matches old color
            g.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);//fill the pixel with the right color
        }
    }
}
g.dispose();
```

Just because i was interested in the topic: relying on image filters you could do all that via:

```
class ColorSwapFilter extends RGBImageFilter {
  int newColor, oldColor;
  public ColorSwapFilter(int newColor, int oldColor) {
    canFilterIndexColorModel = true;
    this.newColor = newColor;
    this.oldColor = oldColor;
  }

  @Override
  public int filterRGB(int x, int y, int rgb) {
    return rgb == oldColor ? newColor : oldColor;
  }
}
```

which should be called via

```
BufferedImage img;//your image
ColorSwapFilter filter = new ColorSwapFilter(...,...);//your colors to be swapped.
ImageProducer producer = img.getSource();
producer = new FilteredImageSource(producer, filter);
Image im = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(producer);
```

Comment: I have made that mistake too many times and am amazed I still make it... Using your method doesn't actually change the white pixels to red for some reason so I have to use mine, but it also draws a partial red image behind the number. I'll look at this further, but thanks for your help.

Comment: @StrongJoshua normally i wouldn´t care, but since you pointed out that the time of the answer made the difference i felt i should point that out. btw i didn´t even know that you could actually change the "accepted answer" :O

Comment: Wouldn't the filterRGB method do the same thing though? However, as what lbalazscs said, I went back to converting pixels (drawing the filled rectangle didn't work as well as I'd hoped anyways), but I now experience a different problem... If you'd still like to help, please look at my response in the question's comments.

Answer (score 3):

You have a semicolon direct after your if statement `if(tmp.equals(old));`

This esentially tells Java that your if statement has only one command associated with it, and  that command is a single semicolon, effectively meaning "do nothing". If you remove it, it will restore the condition on the block of code beneath it, which right now is just running every time regardless of the condition.

Comment: You were first, so I guess you get the accepted answer, but I upvoted them both.

Comment: @StrongJoshua ehhhm, actually i was first ... ^^

Comment: @Kon sorry for "stealing" your points, i just give you an upvote elsewhere :)

Comment: No worries re: points, @luk2302. Just glad to help out somebody.